# IE9 hyphenation problem - hyphen at start of line

Tags: css, internet-explorer-9, hyphenation

In IE9, some posts on our blog hyphenate strangely, with the hyphen appearing on the line after the word break.
For example, in http://yochicago.com/airbnb-%E2%80%93-illegal-short-term-rentals-galore/23326/ "short-term," in the first paragraph, breaks as follows:

short
-term

I've seen this a few other times with this site and another site in development.  And only in IE9.  Compatibility mode "fixes" it.

Since I've been unable to find others writing about this same problem on the Web, I can only assume I've got something amiss in my CSS, but I can't figure it out.

So, two questions:
1. Is anyone else seeing this behavior in IE9?
2. Any suggestions on how to fix it?

Comment: 1. Yes, I'm seeing this in IE9 on your blog. 2. Not sure

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know what is causing the problem, but a quick fix is to apply:

```
<span style="white-space:nowrap">short-</span>term
```

Comment: While this would prevent the strange hyphenation, I can't expect the post authors to remember to do this each time they write a post with a hyphenated word.

Comment: After tracing all the style rules back using IE9's F12 developer tools, I cannot find a single style rule that is causing this. I'm 90% convinced this is a bug in IE9. Anyway, here is a somewhat reduced testcase, maybe if you play around with it further you can find the problem: http://jsfiddle.net/xrHhj/

Comment: Thanks for the assistance.  Pretty much the same conclusion I've come to, but I'm surprised I haven't been able to find any other examples on the Web if this is indeed a bug in IE9.

Comment: Update: According to the Microsoft Connect feedback site for IE, this has been a problem since IE8.  
When the IE8 bug was reported on 8/31/2008, Microsoft eventually responded with:  
"At this time we do not plan on fixing this issue in the IE8 time frame. We appreciate the report, but unfortunately we are at a stage where need to choose what we work on to maximize the value for customers and web developers.  
We will track the issue and hope to address it in a future version of IE."

Comment: (continued)  
It was also reported re: IE9 on 7/17/2010 and Microsoft responded: "We were able to validate your feedback. However, based on the limited impact this bug may have, we will not be able to address this bug during this release."

Comment: Update from Microsoft:
"This issue was resolved in Internet Explorer 10 on Windows 8 Release Preview released on 5/31/2012."